# playing LastFM Playlist with JavaScript music player

Tags: javascript, jquery, playlist, last.fm

I want to play a playlist from LastFM.com and I know Soundmanager2 and some other scripts for playing sound and music.

So I need an out-of-the-box working solution, a jQuery / JavaScript Last FM Playlist Player

Are there some ?

Currently the plugin directory of jquery.com is not available: http://plugins.jquery.com/

Got already the playlist with http://www.lastfm.de/api/playlists but they write `Last.fm playlists do not contain streaming content.`

I use this library: https://github.com/matto1990/PHP-Last.fm-API/

Comment: Since this is 100% on the client. What does PHP have to do with it?

Comment: there is the PHP Library I use: https://github.com/matto1990/PHP-Last.fm-API/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research: its not possible but with the Radio API and a paid subscriber account

http://www.lastfm.de/api/radio

Answer (score 0):

You can try this player
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bbncpldmanoknoahidbgmkgobgmhnafh

But it use vk.com to get songs.

Comment: not an app like this one from chrome webstore but a php script / javascript that does this